# Project can't compile after adding admob library

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, admob

When I add adomb library to my project apps stop working without showing any errurs on android studio. [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg2Pe.png)

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
```

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ozayd.azkar"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe conflict version between your app and admob.

try upgrade admob version :

```
//with appcompat & material:
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
```

then sync project again.

If it don't work, try add **resolutionStrategy** in gradle file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
                force 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then clean project and re sync